# Binding data to layout in Recycleview

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I am currently working on my first app on Android studio. I want to bind data to the layouts I am inflating in my recycleview.

This is the relevant part of my data class:

```
public class ContactData {
    public String contactName;
.....
```

This is the relevant part of my layout xml:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name = "Cdata"
            type="com.example.ketchup.ContactData" />
    </data>
    <TextView>
          android:text="@{Cdata.contactName}"
    </TextView>
....
```

I also created a recycleview adapter

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ContactData contactData = mData.get(position);
        View contactEntry = holder.contactEntry;
    .....
```

the inflating an all works fine, I just dont understand how I am supposed to bind the ContactData to the layout.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**add this to onBindViewHolder :**

```
holder.bind(contactData);
```

**and add this class to your adapter:**

```
 public static class adapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ListItemBinding listItemBinding;

        public QuViewHolder(ListItemBinding listItemBinding) {
            super(listItemBinding.getRoot());
            this.listItemBinding = listItemBinding;
        }

        public void bind(ContactData obj) {
            listItemBinding.setCdata(obj);
            listItemBinding.executePendingBindings();
        }
    }
```